# How to use urllib and re to retrieve live price data with Python

Tags: python, urllib

I am attempting to request the price data from [dukascopy.com](http://dukascopy.com) but I am running into a similar problem to [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481505/grabbing-non-html-data-from-a-website-using-python), where the price data itself is not a part of the html. Therefore, when I run my basic urllib code to extract the data:

```
import urllib.request
url = 'https://www.dukascopy.com'
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'}
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers = headers)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read()
print(str(respData))
```

the price data cannot be found. Referring back to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481505/grabbing-non-html-data-from-a-website-using-python), the user Mark found another url that the data was called from. Can this be applied to collect the data here as well?

Comment: You'll need something that emulates a browser and can handle javascript to load the price data. Using Selenium is one option.

Comment: Does dukascopy have a developer friendly way of getting the data? I searched "dukascopy developer" and found a java api and other links. Not sure if any are helpful to you.

Comment: You will also want to make sure that what you are doing doesn't break the terms and services. In some cases scraping without permission can be illegal.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`dryscape`](https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape). You can scrape JavaScript rendered pages with it. Don't parse web pages with regex module. It's not a good idea. Read this why you should not parse HTML pages with regex: [HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use Beautiful for parsing.

```
import dryscrape
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.dukascopy.com'
session = dryscrape.Session()
session.visit(url)
response = session.body()
soup=BeautifulSoup(response)
print soup
```

Comment: Well your answer is not wrong its the OP asked for help doing it with `urllib`.

Comment: @EmettSpeer Anything that gets OP closer to solution can be posted as an answer. And it's valid to say "don't try that, try this instead".

Comment: I didn't mean it that way.

Comment: I was just reading over `dryscape` to see if it would render JavaScript. Thank you for introducing me to it.

Comment: @EmettSpeer Well I don't know how to do it with `urllib`. I'm waiting to learn it from you :P

Comment: I didn't say there was a way to do it with `urllib`. Your answer just didn't give the reason not to use `urllib`.

Comment: @EmettSpeer Actually even I don't know much if it's possible with `urllib` or not. I have just read it from here and there that you cannot parse JS rendered pages with `urllib` or `requests`. Now you are compelling me to find out about it :P. Ok I'll do that and update my answer.

Comment: I would think its possible to do with `urllib` but only if you have away to render the JavaScript which would require some kind of 3rd party package. There is `PyQt4.QtWebKit`, `pythonwebkit` though I don't know if its maintained. That's all I could find right now.

Comment: Hmm.. Thanks. People also use `selenium` it's very slow but very flexible.

Comment: from reading over the ghost.py documentation it seems to be very selenium like. There is also some headless browsers that you can use with selenium such as `phantomjs`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, though I would prefer to find the source of the data directly and avoid having to install additional modules.